# Mostrar aleatoriamente diferentes banderas del mundo y que se permita adivinar una respuesta

Tags: python, tkinter

Quiero crear un programa que me permita estudiar las banderas de los diferentes países del mundo, por ejemplo que por medio de una función me permita iniciar el juego con un botón de "empezar" y una vez se presione ese botón se abra otra ventana preguntando "a qué país pertenece esta bandera", mostrar una bandera random desde mi carpeta de imágenes y poder verificar si la respuesta escrita es falsa o verdadera.

```
import tkinter as tk

from tkinter import ttk

from tkinter import *

import random


def abrir_ventana_secundaria():

    # Crear una ventana secundaria.

    ventana_secundaria = tk.Toplevel()

    ventana_secundaria.title("Ventana secundaria")

    ventana_secundaria.config(width=300, height=200)

    widget = Label(None, text=' ¿A que país pertenece esta bandera? ')

    
widget.pack()

widget.mainloop() 

    ventana = Tk()
    img = PhotoImage(file="img.png",)

    widget = Label(ventana, image=img).pack()

    ventana.mainloop() 



    # para cerrar la misma.

    boton_cerrar = ttk.Button(

        ventana_secundaria,

        text="Volver a menú principal", 

        command=ventana_secundaria.destroy
    )

    boton_cerrar.place(x=75, y=75)

# Crear la ventana principal.

ventana_principal = tk.Tk()

ventana_principal.config(width=400, height=300)

ventana_principal.title("Menú principal")

# Crear un botón dentro de la ventana principal

# que al ejecutarse invoca a la función

# abrir_ventana_secundaria().

boton_salir = ttk.Button(

        ventana_principal,

        text="Salir", 

        command=ventana_principal.destroy

)


boton_abrir = ttk.Button(

    ventana_principal,

    text="Jugar",

    command=abrir_ventana_secundaria,

)

boton_abrir.place(x=150, y=100)

boton_salir.place(x=150, y=200)

ventana_principal.mainloop()
```

No sé cómo hacer para el programa seleccione una imagen al azar dentro de mi carpeta de imágenes para así adivinar las banderas de forma aleatoria.

Comment: Hola Nicolas, bienvenido, Para que podamos ayudarte, necesitamos ver tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), y si recibes errores, indica cuales son. mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla

Comment: Bienvenidx a SOes. Te faltó contarnos cuál es el problema con el código que nos compartes. Puedes [edit] y contarnos

Comment: Para seleccionar algo al azar, debes hacer por ejemplo una lista de los archivos, y luego numerarlos, y seleccionar con alguna funcion de random, una de las filas..y ahi tenes tu bandera al azar....

Comment: Entiendo muchas gracias, pero como hago para poner las imágenes de las banderas en la lista para que sean seleccionadas las imágenes dentro de la lista de forma aleatoria y se muestre en un cuadro, digamos que la parte para meter le texto de la adivinanza lo hago con un input pero no se como enlazar o anclar las imágenes de mis carpeta en la lista y que muestre una de esas imágenes aleatoriamente diferente cada vez que se adivinó correctamente una bandera previamente, de nuevo disculpas si no expreso con exactitud lo que pretendo hacer, hago mi mejor esfuerzo, de nuevo muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Un posible esquema de trabajo:

```
arrayNombresArchivos = [ "Chile.jpg", "Peru.jpg", "Brasil.jpg" ]
arrayImagenes = []
```

Dentro de un **for** llenas el array vacio:

```
for i in  range( len( arrayNombresArchivos )):
    arrayImagenes.append( tk.PhotoImage( file = "rutaArchivo/" + arrayNombresArchivos[ i ] ))
```

Luego solo tienes que generar un número aleatorio, le pides a ***arrayImagenes*** la imagen correspondiente, la muestras, y cuando tienes la respuesta del jugador, la concatenas con ".jpg" y la comparas con el contenido de ***arrayNombresArchivos***.
Espero haberte orientado un poco.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143132/discussion-on-answer-by-marce-puente-mostrar-aleatoriamente-diferentes-banderas); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.